# How to create a model class and access the values from JSON response using Codable in ios swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, model-view-controller, codable

I'm learning how to create a model class and using `Codable` protocol how to access the values for JSON response. Using `Alamofire` get a request for API call. Here my code

my model class

```
class UserDic:Codable{
    var batters:Batter?
    var id:Int?
    var name:String?
    var topping:[Topping]?
    var ppu:Int?
    var type:String?
}

class Topping:Codable{
    var type:String?
    var id:Int?
}

class Batter:Codable{
    var id:Int?
    var type:String?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var userTbl: UITableView!
    var url:String!
    var toppingVal:[Topping] = []



    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            url = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bUNhsLXzVK?indent=2"
            Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    print("response--->",response)
                    guard response.data != nil else { return }
                    do{
                        let jsonResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserDic.self, from: Data(response.data!))
                        self.toppingVal = jsonResponse.topping!
                        self.userTbl.reloadData()

                        }
                        print("reslut pass the :\(String(describing: jsonResponse.type))")
                    }catch{
                        print("Failed pass the :\(error)")
                    }


            }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return toppingVal.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = userTbl.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserCell")

        let aUser = toppingVal[indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = String(aUser.id!)

        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

my question: Kindly view my json response and check my model class.How can i access the batters values and list in the UUtableview. Thanks advance.

Comment: what's your problem ?

Comment: In my API response i want to access the "batters": {
  "batter": [
    {
      "type": "Regular",
      "id": 1001
    },
    {
      "type": "Blueberry",
      "id": 1003
    },
  ]
} using model class using Codable protocol. help me.

Comment: see below correct json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
// MARK: - Empty
struct UserDic: Codable {
    let topping: [Topping]
    let name: String
    let batters: Batters
    let ppu: Double
    let type: String
    let id: Int
}

// MARK: - Batters
struct Batters: Codable {
    let batter: [Topping]
}

// MARK: - Topping
struct Topping: Codable {
    let type: String
    let id: Int
}
```

---

```
let jsonResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserDic.self, from: Data(response.data!))
self.toppingVal = jsonResponse.batters.batter
self.userTbl.reloadData()
```

Comment: store the topping value in  var toppingVal:[Topping] = [] Array. How can i store the batters values?

Comment: create another array with same type

Comment: what kind of array created var batterVal:[Batter] = [] this array but show Error: "Cannot assign value of type '[Topping]?' to type '[Batter]'" Help me?

Comment: you need `var batterVal = [Topping]() `

Comment: Thanks you so much for ur help!. how can learn quick for working MVC model class with out error. refer any link. its useful to me.